# Convergence of integrals - both finite but different

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Given a measure space, is it possible to have a sequence of integrable functions that converges pointwise, such that the integral of the limit differs from the limit of the sequence of integrals, both quantities being finite ?
All counterexamples I've seen illustrating the utility of Lebesgue's convergence theorems involve at least one of those quantities being infinite. I'm thinking some kind of function with a triangle somewhere that rises and gets narrower such that the area remains constant would do it but I can't quite reach my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } 0<x<\dfrac 1 n, \\[10pt] 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Then $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\,dx = 1$ for all $n$, and $\lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} f_n(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Great minds think alike: I see arkeet posted this same example.  (Actually it's a standard example.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

If
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n \le x \le n + 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
or
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1/n & \text{if }0 \le x \le n \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
or
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n & \text{if }0 < x \le 1/n \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n = 1$, but $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. The last one is probably closest to what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes it is, and it actually enables to build exactly what I almost had in mind for whoever has the patience to write it down to replace the plateau by a triangle of height 2n. But I like the second one cause it converges uniformly, and still meets my requests